# Obsolete browser to access old switch and other apparatus

Tags: interface

Sometimes I need to log in to old network apparatus web interfaces, that either have https with unsupported ciphers or need java plugin in the browser. With recent versions of Chrome, Firefox or IE this is not possible anymore. What do you use in this situations?

Comment: I have an old Windows XP virtualbox image for such things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an old Firefox Portable image, maybe a 3.x or 4.x one

Comment: Does that include a java environment? That's a common problem when accessing old management interfaces.

Comment: You had to install an old Java version (<= 1.6) in this case.